# How to insert the Homebrew directory at the top of your PATH environment variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal, installation

I need little help here. For your information, I'm a very new to Python, and just trying to tinker with it. So, I have this website **'The hitchhiker's guide to python'**. Now, I'm on a section of **'Installing Python 3 on Mac OS X'**. Here is the link -> http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/osx/#pip

Anyway I wanted to do it right, so freshly formatted my Mac, and Xcode as well. And I followed the instruction which says **'xcode-select --install'** . After that, I started install homebrew within the terminal `$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

I guess I coped with this until now, but here is the problem occurs.
He says

> Once you’ve installed Homebrew, insert the Homebrew directory at the
>   top of your PATH environment variable. You can do this by adding the
>   following line at the bottom of your ~/.profile file

So, with some searches, I edited my path in nano. by following

```
 sudo nano /etc/paths

/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin   <<<--When I opened the paths, there wasn't this 'usr/local/sbin' So I typed it.
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin/
/sbin
```

When I opened the path, there was no `'/usr/local/sbin'`. so I typed it.
And I quit the terminal, echo the path out, nothing happend.
If I do `which python` it shows me `/usr/bin/python`.
I do have python3 installed, But when I do `python -V`, it's still 
**Python 2.7.10**

How can I insert the Homebrew directory at the top of your PATH environment variable?

By means, How can I set my mac to set python3 to default???

Appreciate it in advance!

Comment: What is the question in the end? *Homebrew in the PATH env* or *python3 default*?

Comment: python3 default. When I do 'python -V', it just shows me 'python 2.7.10'

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood the instructions about the PATH. PATH is an environment variable which can be set in the `.profile` file in your home directory *(create it if it doesn't exist)*, and you need to copy exactly what the page said to the bottom of the file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Once this is done, restart your Terminal and you should be able to use the `python3` command.

Comment: There was '.profile' when I typed 'ls -a' in the terminal. So I opened it with nano, added this line but still no luck. If I do 'python --version', it still shows me python '2.7.10'.

Comment: Yes, because it's going to be `python3`, not just `python`.

Comment: For clarity, what exactly is meant by "home directory?"  1.  I have a "/home" folder on my system which has no files in it.  2.  I also have this, which some sites refer to as one's 'home directory', "/Users/myusername"

Comment: The home directory is whatever your operating system defines it to be. You can examine your entry in `/etc/passwd` or simply `echo "$HOME"` to display it. On Linux, your home directory would commonly be in `/home/you`; on MacOS, try `/Users/you` (where `you` is your login name). On other platforms, other locations like `/user/you` or `/export/home/you` were once common. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory

Answer (score 0):

Go to your terminal and run:

```
$ which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

you will get your brew path and make sure you add this path to *~/.profile* PATH like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Then run this to make changes effective:

```
$ source ~/.profile
```

Comment: I ran 'which brew' and it shows me exactly like above, and added that second line to the '.profile' and restarted terminal and ran third line, but no luck. But What is '~/.profile'??? There's just '.profile' when I type 'ls -a'.

Comment: Try `echo ~` and `echo $HOME` you will understand. `~` sign represents the home directory.

Comment: That's why we do 'cd ~' to go home directory, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The file in /etc/ is only run at startup, and is global over all users. I suggest you use the files in your home directory (.bash_profile or .zshrc depending on your shell). These files are read every time a terminal is opened.

Add this line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

To update an existing terminal, you can update the settings by

```
> source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: In my home directory, which can be go with 'cd ~'. Anyway in my home directory, I did 'ls -a', and there's just 3 things that start with .bashxxxxx, which is '.bash_history', '.bash_sessions', and '.bashrc'. There's no '.bash_profile' or '.zshrc'.

Comment: Bashrc is the one!

Comment: Thanks! I added. But I'm not sure it is working. I'm going through this website's instruction but it's getting me stuck.